# Split string using regular expression, how to ignore apostrophe?

Tags: python, regex, split

I am doing a spell check tutorial in Python and it uses this regular expression:

```
import re
def split_line(line):
    return re.findall('[A-Za-z]+(?:\`[A-Za-z)+)?',line)
```

I was wondering if you could help me change this function so it will ignore `'`, i.e. if I input the string `he's` i will get `['he's']` and not `['he','s']`.

Comment: Does it even compile? This  `[A-Za-z)`  should be `[A-Za-z]` (closing parenthesis is wrong).

Comment: Can you show us an example of `line` and what should be the expected output ?

Comment: You want an apostrophe ', but use a backquote `  why?. `[A-Za-z]+(?:\'[A-Za-z]+)?` should do the trick.

Comment: opps typo on the parenthesis should be square. but my question still stands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll need to fix the original expression by replacing `)` with `]` as mentioned by Marcin. Then simply add `'` to the list of allowed characters (escaped by a back-slash):

```
import re
def split_line(line):
    return re.findall('[A-Za-z\']+(?:\`[A-Za-z]+)?',line)

split_line("He's my hero")

#["He's", 'my', 'hero']
```

Of course, this will not consider any edge cases where the apostrophe is at the beginning or at the end of a word.

Comment: Cheers Matt perfect.
:P which makes me ask the question how to I get it to consider edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is supposed to match one or more letters and then an optional occurrence of a backtick and again one or more letters. You can put the backtick into a character class and add `'` into the class.

Note that you do not need to escape `'` if you use a double-quoted string literal:

```py
re.findall(r"[A-Za-z]+(?:['`][A-Za-z]+)*", line)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/porrJA/1). *Details*:

- `[A-Za-z]+` - one or more ASCII letters (use `[^\W\d_]+` to match any one or more Unicode letters)
- `` (?:['`][A-Za-z]+)* `` - zero or more occurrences of `'` or backtick followed with one or more ASCII letters.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/9B5jXS):

```py
import re
text = "And he's done it o`key!"
print(re.findall(r"[A-Za-z]+(?:['`][A-Za-z]+)*", text))
# => ['And', "he's", 'done', 'it', 'o`key']
```